# What's the difference between row and column majors?

Tags: c++

Multidimensional arrays can be stored in linear memory in two orders: row-major and column-major. What is the difference between these two orders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Row Major will search through information as:

```
[0][0],[0][1],...,[0][n],[1][0],...,[1][n],..[m][n]
```

Column Major will search through info information as:

```
[0][0],[1][0],...,[m][0],[0][1],...,[m][1],...,[m][n]
```

In memory it is always stored as:

```
[0][0],[0][1],...,[0][n],[1][0],...,[1][n],..[m][n]
```

Answer (score 3):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

> The difference is simply that in row-major order, consecutive elements of the rows of the array are contiguous in memory; in column-major order, consecutive elements of the columns are contiguous.

Answer (score -2):

There are no multidimensional arrays in C++, so this question is moot.

Comment: It's pretty common to use that term for an array of an array type, though.  e.g. `int foo[4][4]`.  And even if you simulate a multidimensional array on top of a 1d array (like `bar[i*4 + j]`), it's very much *not* a moot point for performance.  It just makes it more obvious whether or not you're accessing contiguous memory, unlike with `[][]` where a novice might have to look up `[]` associates left to right or right to left.